# Is there a way to comment out a mulitline of code?

Tags: anylogic

Are there a shortcuts-key combination to comment out a block of code in anylogic?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
code line 1
code line 2
code line 3
```

Into:

```
//code line 1
//code line 2
//code line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "shortcut" but Java allows multi-line commenting:

```
some code
// comment for 1 line
more code

/*
multi-line comment
across several ines
*/
```

Also, always check the [AnyLogic help](https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/comments.html#comments), it has this covered as well

Comment: Sure. Seems like the only option. Just enjoyed the super-fast shortcut-keys in intelliJ and got a little spoiled I guess :P

Comment: Yeah, avoid getting spoiled by other IDEs :D